# How to after moving the image back to the beginning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

Hello I'm using a plugin called spritespin (http://spritespin.ginie.eu/), but after I do an interaction in the image with move mouse mode it does not move back to the initial frame.

```
 $(function() {
  $('.spritespin').spritespin({
    source: SpriteSpin.sourceArray('/images/rad_zoom_{frame}.jpg', { frame: [1,34], digits: 3 }),
    width: 480,
    height: 327,
    sense: -1,
    animate: false,
    plugins: [
      '360',
      'move'
    ]
  });
})
```

Comment: Please format your code so that it's more readable.

Comment: I formatted the code